# Android: Hide DrawerLayout menu panel in Android Studio layout editor

Tags: android, android-studio

Well as the title says I need to hide drawer menu in android studio layout editor so I can see other views underneath. Here is a picture

[image]

Is there xml attribute that can do the trick ? 
Note I don't need to hide or show it programmatically, I just need to hide it in xml so in editor preview it doesn't hide view elements that lay under.

Comment: Isn't there something like a `tools:openDrawer` attribute on the `<DrawerLayout>` element that controls that?

Comment: such an obvious thing :) but that's 90% the answer , tools:openDrawer="end" does exactly what needed

Comment: If you want to hide it, then just remove that line. You shouldn't need to explicitly set it to a non-existent drawer, I would think.

Comment: yeah, it was there all the time and I don't know why when last time I was digging and removed even change value it didn't take an effect so I thought that there is other way. perhaps was an android studio hung. Anyway you can add your comment as an answer. I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tools:openDrawer` attribute on the `<DrawerLayout>` element controls which drawers are shown in the layout preview. Simply removing that line should cause no drawers to be shown. However, if that doesn't work as expected, for some reason, it seems that setting the attribute to a non-existent drawer gravity works, too.